# Winform DataGridView - Bind/Consume JSON Webservice?

Tags: c#, winforms, json, datagridview

I have a winform application that contains a datagridview that I would like to populate using a JSON webservice. I am not having much luck finding any examples on the web, is this possible?

The webservice can output XML or JSON and the XML is no problem but I feel that the JSON would provide a quicker response.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to mimic the json structure and then use the javascript serializer to convert json response to a bindable list

```
var myList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<MyClass>>(json);
```

[This](http://www.google.com.ar/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=es&source=hp&q=Deserialize+JavaScriptSerializer&pbx=1&oq=Deserialize+JavaScriptSerializer&aq=f&aqi=g-L1g-jvL1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4062l4062l1l4782l1l1l0l0l0l0l302l302l3-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=1d18422a411a50c&biw=918&bih=534) google search gives you some complete examples about how to deserialize a json object using the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class

Comment: I feel this only answers half of the question. He didn't just ask how to deserialize an object. How do you now bind your data grid with your List of objects?