# Convert MySQL / JSON data into a table

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, plugins, tabular

Bit more complicated than the subject lets on.  I'm basically running an SQL query that returns 4 columns of data.  The last column is a number, the first 3 contain information about the number.

Specifically:

```
Col1: Question Text
Col2: Info Type
Col3: Banner
Col4: Average
```

So I'm querying a large dataset to get the average score of a bunch of items.

I might query to get the results for Q1 and Q2, where Info Type is Favourite or Second Favourite, Banners are Canada and the USA.

What I want my output table to look like is:

```
               |Canada           |USA
Q1 | Favourite | Average Score   | Average Score
Q1 | SecondFav | Average Score   | Average Score
Q2 | Favourite | Average Score   | Average Score
Q2 | SecondFav | Average Score   | Average Score
```

I'm looking for a way (maybe a plugin or util) where I can specify which data to use in rows and which in columns.

Not sure how clear that was, any help is appreciated.

Comment: With jquery you can easily cycle through the result set and format it into a table and column structure.  IF your output is to a datagridview, you might want to look at the Dojo toolkit http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/populating_datagrid/

or look at this question for another option.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704122/winform-datagridview-bind-consume-json-webservice

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in mysql, just pivot your rows into columns using `CASE` statement something like:

```
 Select col1 as 'Question', col2 as 'Info Type',
        case when Col3 = 'Canada' then col4 end as 'Canada',
        case when Col3 = 'USA' then col4 end as 'USA'
 from yourTableName
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  Any idea on how to make it dynamic? So that whatever is in Col3 just always gets added as a new column?